# How to manage database changes while upgrading application versions in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

With every upgrade there is some change in database schema? The change could alteration of column types or addition/deletion of columns.

This forces a reinstall of app ie., uninstall older version and then download app again from the android market.

Is there a best practice to follow so that old data is copied during app installation and reinitialized with newer schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your implementation of SqliteOpenHelper override method [`onUpgrade()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29).